# Quantity sold for each Category report

Tags: magento-1.7, category, reports, category-tree

I'm attempting to create a report based on the category and the quantity sold for that category. So two columns: Category and Quantity Sold.

Pretty much as you see in this report here with the category name and the quantity ordered 
http://reports.demo.mirasvit.com/admin/?demo=demo (Advanced Reprots->Sales->Sales by Category)

I know magento doesn't associate a sale with a category so i'm quite stuck on this and appreciate any help. Pulling out a category tree list as ordered in the admin would be a start but I can't even seem to do that at the moment!